# Stack around the variable "l" was corrupted

Tags: c, struct

Написал свой лист на c. Но при завершении программы вылетает с ошибкой: Run-Time Check Failure #2 Stack around the variable "l" was corrupted.

main.c:

```
#include "objects.h"

int main() {
   list l;
   init_list(&l);
   return 0;
}
```

object.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct _comp {
   struct _comp *next;
   struct _comp *prev;
} comp;

typedef struct _list {
   comp *first;
   comp *tail;
} *list;

void  init_list(list l) {
   comp *first = (comp*)malloc(sizeof(comp));
   if (first == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   comp *last = (comp*)malloc(sizeof(comp));
   if (last == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   first->prev = NULL;
   last->next = NULL;
   first->next = last;
   last->prev = first;
   l->first = first;
   l->tail = last;
}
```

objects.h

```
typedef struct _list *list;
void init_list(list l);
```

Comment: Для начала - вы нигде не ошиблись? `void init_list(list l);` и `list l;
   init_list(&l);`? Именно так и работаете?

Comment: @Harry, на данный момент в коде написано именно так, потому что init_list(l) вообще не работает(использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "l"). Аналогичный трюк у меня работал до этого. Меня больше интересует почему программа вылетает в самом конце, когда все функции завершились.

Comment: Нет никакого смысла рассуждать о вылете программы, которая даже не компилируется. Вам компилятор выдал стандартное диагностическое сообщение. Дальше не о чем говорить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень нездоровое занятие - веревочками подвязывать колесо у автомобиля, если болт туда не лезет - это к вашему

> потому что init_list(l) вообще не работает(использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "l")

Ну и почему вы ее не инициализировали? Сочли, что правильный болт - роскошь, отделаемся веревочкой?

Вы не выделили память, соответственно, вот тут

```
l->first = first;
l->tail = last;
```

запортили стек.

Подметенные под коврик объедки - чтоб никто не увидел - начинают вонять...

Давайте сделаем уборку.

```
list l = malloc(sizeof(*list));
init_list(l);
```